How to make ListView scroll to bottom of page and back up again on the press of a button?
I have a GestureDetector wrapped around a Container, which displays a web page when pressed. This Container is currently being called in a different view which contains a ListView.
Here’s what currently works:
When the GestureDetector is pressed, the web page slides in nicely, as expected.
When pressed again, the web page slides out, just as intended.
The problem:
After the web page slides in, the user will need to scroll down to see the full web page content.
When the user presses the GestureDetector again, the web page slides out, and the user has to scroll back up.
How can I make the ListView automatically scroll to the bottom when the web page is first displayed (Gesture Detector is first pressed), and scroll back up when the web page is hidden? (Gesture Detector is pressed again) I want this to happen dynamically based on the user's interaction with the GestureDetector, as this will add a nice refinement to the user experience. I do not have much experience with Flutter Animations and controllers, so any help is appreciated.
Here is the code for the main view where the Container is being called:
class ADJParity_Screen extends StatefulWidget {
  const ADJParity_Screen({super.key});

  @override
  State<ADJParity_Screen> createState() => _ADJParity_ScreenState();
}

class _ADJParity_ScreenState extends State<ADJParity_Screen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    ScrollController _scrollController = ScrollController();
    // return WebPage(); // For testing purposes
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Main View'),
        titleTextStyle:
        const TextStyle(color: Colors.deepOrangeAccent, fontSize: 23),
      ),
      body: ListView(
        children: <Widget>[
          const Center(
            child: Image(
              image: AssetImage(
                'images/aaaBR.png',
              ),
              height: 175,
              width: 175,
            ),
          ),
          const SizedBox(height: 10),
          Container(
            height: 80,
            width: 380,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
              color: Colors.green.shade600,
            ),
            child: const Center(
              child: Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 8.0),
                child: Text(
                  "This is text",
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          const SizedBox(height: 40), //300
   
          const SlidingWebViewWidget(
            url: 'https://url-link-here-example', // ***This is where I am calling the
                                                     Container***
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

Here is the code to the view which contains said container; this is the code that handles the animations:
class SlidingWebViewWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final String url;
  const SlidingWebViewWidget({super.key, required this.url});

  @override
  _SlidingWebViewWidgetState createState() => _SlidingWebViewWidgetState();
}

class _SlidingWebViewWidgetState extends State<SlidingWebViewWidget>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  late AnimationController _animationController;
  late Animation<Offset> _slideAnimation;
  bool _isVisible = false;
  ScrollController _scrollController = ScrollController();

  final WebViewController _controller = WebViewController();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _animationController = AnimationController(
      duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 300),
      vsync: this,
    );

    _slideAnimation = Tween<Offset>(
      begin: const Offset(1, 0),
      end: const Offset(0, 0),
    ).animate(CurvedAnimation(
      parent: _animationController,
      curve: Curves.easeInOut,
    ));

    _controller
      ..setJavaScriptMode(JavaScriptMode.unrestricted)
      ..loadRequest(Uri.parse(widget.url));
  }

  void toggleVisibility() {
    setState(() {
      _isVisible = !_isVisible;
      _isVisible
          ? _animationController.forward()
          : _animationController.reverse();
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _animationController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double screenHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    return Column(
      children: [
        GestureDetector(
          // onTap: (){
          //   _scrollController.animateTo(
          //     _scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent,
          //     duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 300),
          //     curve: Curves.easeOut,
          //   );
          // },   // Ignore; this was used for a (failed) attempt.
          onTap: toggleVisibility,
          child: Container(
            height: 60,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
              color: Colors.orangeAccent,
            ),
            child: const Center(
              child: Text(
                "Visualize",
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 25),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        SlideTransition(
          position: _slideAnimation,
          child: Container(
            height: screenHeight / 2,  // Adjust the height as needed
            color: Colors.black38,
            child: WebPage(url: widget.url),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}


Here is a demo code
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    
    void main() {
      runApp(const MaterialApp(
        home: ScrollDemo(),
      ));
    }
    
    class ScrollDemo extends StatefulWidget {
      const ScrollDemo({super.key});
    
      @override
      State<ScrollDemo> createState() => _ScrollDemoState();
    }
    
    class _ScrollDemoState extends State<ScrollDemo> {
      final ScrollController _scrollController = ScrollController();
    
      @override
      void dispose() {
        _scrollController.dispose();
        super.dispose();
      }
    
      void _scrollToBottom() {
        _scrollController
            .animateTo(
              _scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent,
              duration: const Duration(seconds: 4),
              curve: Curves.easeInOut,
            )
            .whenComplete(() => _scrollToTop());
      }
    
      void _scrollToTop() {
        _scrollController.animateTo(
          0.0,
          duration: const Duration(seconds: 2),
          curve: Curves.easeInOut,
        );
      }
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Scroll Demo')),
          body: Column(
            children: [
              Expanded(
                child: ListView.builder(
                  controller: _scrollController,
                  itemCount: 50,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    return ListTile(
                      title: Text('Item $index'),
                    );
                  },
                ),
              ),
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                children: [
                  ElevatedButton(
                    onPressed: _scrollToBottom,
                    child: const Text('Scroll to Bottom'),
                  ),
                  ElevatedButton(
                    onPressed: _scrollToTop,
                    child: const Text('Scroll to Top'),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
        );
      }
    }

